# How can I show the latest data by date using sort in react typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, react-typescript

My date format is like this: **Mon Mar 07 2022** and I want to show the latest data. I have tried this way but it's not working.

If I put new Date() into my code I got this error: `var Date: DateConstructor new (value: string | number | Date) => Date (+3 overloads) The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        fetch(`http://localhost:5000/dashboard/orders`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                const latestData = data.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
// const latestData = data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) -new Date( a.date)) // error
                setOrders(latestData)
            })
            .finally(() => setIsLoading(false))
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typescript error, the sort comparator function accepts only numbers.

**Note:** Without getTime it works in javascript.

```js
const data = [{
    date: "Mon Mar 07 2022",
  },
  {
    date: "Mon Mar 01 2022",
  },
  {
    date: "Mon Mar 06 2022",
  },
];
const latestData = data.sort(
  (a, b) => new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()
);
console.log(latestData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this way

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```